# Creating simple Custom Post Type in Combination with Elementor Pro

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I'm trying to achieve of how to sort out the following task - I'm trying to find out how to create a list of objects, let's say a directory of objects of a real estate company (see attached mockup image). Some of the objects might be linked to a page with more details and some a just for getting displayed in the record list without a detail page. I'm also working with Elementor Pro which has a built in feature to display posts and depending category/taxonomies (see attached mockup image), so I thought of creating a custom post type for these records. Is there a way this can be done and the records displayed like it's shown in the attached mockup?

[image: Records Mockup]

Frontend Style of the records is not a problem, just not sure how to integrate them the best way.
Can this be done without another Plugin? Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to make a custom layout for the post grid. If that is the case I recommend you check out https://wordpress.org/plugins/ele-custom-skin/, which does exactly that. The free version should suffice

Comment: Yes, Elementor Custom Skin was the plugin I came across that finally helped me to design the rendering of my custom post type. I hope for a non plugin solution, but haven't found one yet. Thanks!

Comment: If you know PHP you can do it without a plugin by creating a new skin for the Posts widget.

Answer (score 1):

U can use Elementor Pro with jet Engine

Jen Engine lets u create the post type + it lets u crete listings, the permits u to create the design for the loop and in elementor pro just drag the listings options and choose the skin for the post type.

[image]

Create a listing design
[image]

When your creating a listing will tell you to specify what post type you wanna loop
[image]

At last go to your page and add the listing
[image]

Finaly just configure the query and the grid. Thats all

Remember you can add met fields for extra info, and in the listing design you import your dinamic field. As in the image of my listing describes. The 100 and the price is a dinamic field.

[image]

[image]